# what are the common symbols in objdump?

Tags: gcc, binutils

I'm reading the documentation of objdump in : 
[objdump manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/binutils/objdump.html#objdump)

and in the line that specifies the output of the symbol table for ELF based files entries with the -t option, there's one line that i would like to better understand. I copied that part of the documentation here to clarify. My question is, for the common symbols, objdump show the alignment, but what are considered the common symbols? 

Thanks in advance.

---

**Documentation content**

> The other common output format, usually seen with ELF based files,
>   looks like this:
>
> ```
>       00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
>       00000000 g       .text  00000000 fred
> ```
>
> Here the first number is the symbol's value (sometimes refered to as its address). The next field is actually a set of characters and
>   spaces indicating the flag bits that are set on the symbol. These
>   characters are described below. Next is the section with which the
>   symbol is associated or *ABS* if the section is absolute (ie not
>   connected with any section), or *UND* if the section is referenced in
>   the file being dumped, but not defined there.
>
> After the section name comes another field, a number, which for common
>   symbols is the alignment and for other symbol is the size. Finally the
>   symbol's name is displayed.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking: do mean to ask what symbols show up often, or something else?

Comment: I don't understand what is a common symbol. For example, if i define an integer variable, that's a common symbol?

Comment: Oh, I see now; the documentation has a special meaning for the term "common", in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely familiar with this terminology, but I believe "common symbol" refers to symbols in the "common variable storage", which means the `.bss` section. See [the assembler documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/bss.html#index-common-variable-storage-207).

The `.bss` section is used for data which is uninitialised (or zero-initialized) when the program starts. This data has no value stored in the object file, so a file offset would be inappropriate.

Non-common-variable-storage symbols are variables, functions, etc. that are associated with data or code stored in the object file, and which will be loaded into memory at run time.